# Ionic 2 cloud auth in Angular 2 website

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-cloud, ionic-auth-service

We are building a desktop website equivalent to the services provided in our Ionic 2 app. Website will be Angular 2 site.

We are planning to use Ionic cloud for **auth**. 
https://ionic.io/cloud#authentication

Can we use the same auth in our website? We would want to avoid duplicate work.

Thanks

Comment: I know of another provider that can do that. But my preference would be ionic cloud too if it is easy to set up the auth for our web & api

Comment: It did not turn out to be straight forward. We ended up using Firebase.

Comment: thanks for sharing..really time consuming to test them